# .htaccess regex beginner redirection problem

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm a beginner in redirecting with htaccess. I wanted to do a small redirect, but am already stuck.

My first redirect was:

```
RewriteRule ^/project/(.*) /search/?type=details&projectid=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which works fine. The problem is, that if the link gets shared on facebook, the outbound link of facebook is added with a ?fbclid=XXX. So my links get turned into:

```
/search/?type=details&projectid=1?fbclid=XXX
```

So now I somehow have to find the "?fbclid=XXX" (in case there is one) and stick it behind a &. For now I have:

```
RewriteRule ^/project/([^/]*)/?(.*)$ /search/?type=details&projectid=$1&$2 [R=301,L]
```

But this only works if there is a / inbetween the projectid and ?fbclid.

Can anyone give me a clue, what I'm missing?
thank you very much.

Comment: You are trying to fix a symptom instead of curing the cause. Rarely a good idea.

Comment: You cannot capture a query string inside a `RewriteRule`. You'd need to do that with the help of a `RewriteCond`. That is clearly documented ... And you will find endless examples for that here on SO. But that URL you are looking at is invalid anyway, it violates the specification, so it is undefined how it is handled by browsers or servers (or stuff in between).

Comment: Bottom line: do not publish links like `/search/?type=details&projectid=1`, always use pretty URLs like `/search/type/details/projectid/1` instead and internally rewrite those when they get requested. That would result in a _valid_ URL even if facebook get's hold of it.